# How to change date from "mm-dd-yy" to "yy-mm-dd"?

Tags: ruby

```
date = "21-12-2013"
```

in a db table, I have a date column with `"20131221"`, and I need to compare the date. Is the format wrong? How can I change the format form `dd-mm-yy` to `yy-mm-dd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression ([`String#sub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-sub)):

```
date = "21-12-2013"
date.sub(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/, '\3-\2-\1')
# => "2013-12-21"
```

Using [`DateTime::strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and [`DateTime#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime):

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# => "2013-12-21"
```